# For Loop in Python Error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, runtime-error, series

why this for loop does not work...?

I want to get a new column with Delivery Year, it consists of these columns, however, there are a lot of Nans so the logic is that the for loop goes through columns and returns the first non-Na value. The best-case scenario is Delivery Date, when this is not there then Build Year if even this is not there then at least In-Service Date when the machine was set into work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Platform ID' : [1,2,3,4], "Delivery Date" : [str(2009), float("nan"), float("nan"), float("nan")],
                                              "Build Year" : [float("nan"),str(2009),float("nan"), float("nan")], 
                                              "In Service Date" : [float("nan"),str("14-11-2010"), str("14-11-2009"), float("nan")]})
df.dtypes
df
```

```
def delivery_year(delivery_year, build_year, service_year):
    out = []
    for i in range(0,len(delivery_year)):
        if delivery_year.notna():
            out[i].append(delivery_year)
        if (delivery_year[i].isna() and build_year[i].notna()):
            out[i].append(build_year)
        elif build_year[i].isna():
            out[i].append(service_year.str.strip().str[-4:])
        else:
            out[i].append(float("nan"))
    return out

df["Delivery Year"] = delivery_year(df["Delivery Date"], df["Build Year"], df["In Service Date"])
```

When I run this function I get this error and I do not know why...

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The expected output (column Delivery Year):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 3**

I rewrote your function in the same manner of your, so without change the logic and the type of your columns. I let you compare the two versions:

```
def delivery_year(delivery_date, build_year, service_year):
    out = []
    for i in range(len(delivery_date)):
        if pd.notna(delivery_date[i]):
            out.append(delivery_date[i])
        elif pd.isna(delivery_date[i]) and pd.notna(build_year[i]):
            out.append(build_year[i])
        elif pd.isna(build_year[i]) and pd.notna(service_year[i]):
            out.append(service_year[i].strip()[-4:])
        else:
            out.append(float("nan"))
    return out

df["Delivery Year"] = delivery_year(df["Delivery Date"],
                                    df["Build Year"],
                                    df["In Service Date"])
```

Notes:

1. I changed the name of your first parameter because `delivery_year` is also the name of your function, so it can be confusing.
2. I also replaced the `.isna()` and `.notna()` methods by their equivalent functions: `pd.isna(...)` and `pd.notna(...)`.
3. The second `if` became `elif`

**Update 2**

Use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) to replace your function. `combine_first` updates first series ('Delivery Date') with the second series where values are `NaN`. You can chain them to fill your 'Delivery Year'.

```
df['Delivery Year'] = df['Delivery Date'] \
                          .combine_first(df['Build Year']) \
                          .combine_first(df['In Service Date'].str[-4:])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Platform ID Delivery Date Build Year In Service Date Delivery Year
0            1          2009        NaN             NaN          2009
1            2           NaN       2009      14-11-2010          2009
2            3           NaN        NaN      14-11-2009          2009
3            4           NaN        NaN             NaN           NaN
```

**Update**

You forgot the `[i]`:

```
if delivery_year[i].notna():
```

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous:

```
>>> delivery_year.notna()
0     True  # <- 2009
1    False  # <- NaN
2    False
3    False
Name: Delivery Date, dtype: bool
```

Pandas should consider the series is True (2009) or False (NaN)?

You have to aggregate the result with `.any()` or `.all()`

```
>>> delivery_year.notna().any()
True  # because there is at least one non nan-value.

>>> delivery_year.notna().all()
False  # because all values are not nan.
```

Comment: This solved this error, thank you, however I have now a new one: 'str' object has no attribute 'notna' Could you help?

Comment: Please update your post with the expect outcome. You have 2 problems in your function. The first is the datatype of columns and the second is the loop. With Pandas, you should avoid loop.

Comment: Done, I would do it through the for loop as I do know solution with np.where(...)

Comment: I updated my answer. Please can you check? You really want to use a for loop?

Comment: Thank you would it be possible also with for loop? :) I am just learning this and wondering what does not work.

Comment: Thank you very much :))) Really you helped me a lot thank you and let me know if I can vote somewhere for you. I have accepted your answer. You have made my day!

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons for the error is that although your columns Delivery Date, Build Year and In Service Date are of type object, but the NaN values in them are of type float (see screenshot below).

[image]

One of the ways to solve this would be to convert the three columns into str type:

```
df["Delivery Date"] = df["Delivery Date"].astype(str)
df["Build Year"] = df["Build Year"].astype(str)
df["In Service Date"] = df["In Service Date"].astype(str)
```

And then I have modified your function as follows:

```
def delivery_year(delivery_year, build_year, service_year):
    out = []
    for i in range(0,len(delivery_year)):
        if len(delivery_year[i])>=4:
            out.append(delivery_year[i])
        elif (len(delivery_year[i])<4) & (len(build_year[i])>=4):
            out.append(build_year[i])
        elif (len(build_year[i])<4 and len(service_year[i])>=4):
            out.append(service_year[i].split("-")[-1])
        else:
            out.append(float("nan"))
    return out

df["Delivery Year"] = delivery_year(df["Delivery Date"], df["Build Year"], df["In Service Date"])
```

I am checking the length greater than 4 because the length of "NaN" as a string would be checked in the function above which is 3. This would return you the desired additional column as shown in the screenshot attached [image]

Answer (score 0):

your error has the solution as far as I can see.
If you want to trigger the IF-Statements on the first occurence of Non-nan values,
use .any() like this.

```
if delivery_year.notna().any():
            out[i].append(delivery_year)
```

You have to specify that whether you want to filter out 'Any' values from specific columns or 'All' values.
:)